# Kendo TreeView onMouseOver()

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I need to trigger a JavaScript method upon mousing over individual nodes within a Kendo TreeView control. Given a TreeView definition similar to the following:

```
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    checkboxes: false,
    select: onSelect,
    expand: onExpand,
    loadOnDemand: true,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                var id = options.data.id;
                var data = get(localData, id);

                if (data) {
                    options.success(data);
                } else {
                    //fetch data from server
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        schema: { model: { id: "id" } }
    }
});
```

How might I trigger such a mouse over event? Please note that using css hover is insufficient as I need to execute programmatic operations on hover and not just change styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution to this. It is not incredibly direct but it is a workaround for anyone out there experiencing a similar hurdle. The following is one way to add a mouse over event to each node in a TreeView:

```
var allNodes = $(".k-item");
$.each(allNodes, function(index, node) {
    node.onmouseover = function() {
        alert("test");
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the 'k-item k-in' class and use the jQuery's .hover() function

```
$("#treeview").find('.k-item .k-in').each(function () {                
    $(this).off('hover');
    $(this).hover(function () {             
        alert("Hovered!");
    }
}
```